# Understanding how Julia modules can be extended

Tags: module, julia, linear-algebra

I'm struggling to understand how exactly modules can be extended in Julia. Specifically, I'd like to create my own `LinearAlgebra` matrix whose parent class is `AbstractMatrix{T}` and implement its functionality similar to how the `Diagonal` or `UpperTriangular` matrices are implemented in the actual LA package. If I could literally add my matrix to the original package, then I would, but for now I am content creating my own `MyLinearAlgebra` package that simply imports the original and extends it. Here's what I've got so far in `MyLinearAlgebra.jl`:

```
module MyLinearAlgebra

import LinearAlgebra
import Base: getindex, setindex!, size

export
# Types
LocalMatrix,
SolutionVector,
# Functions
issymmetric,
isdiag
# Operators
# Constants

include("SolutionVector.jl")
include("LocalMatrix.jl")

end
```

Focusing solely on `LocalMatrix.jl` now, I have:

```
"""
    struct LocalMatrix{T} <: AbstractMatrix{T}
Block diagonal structure for local matrix. `A[:,:,s,iK]` is a block matrix for
state s and element iK
"""
struct LocalMatrix{T} <: AbstractMatrix{T}
    data::Array{T,4}

    function LocalMatrix{T}(data) where {T}
        new{T}(data)
    end
end
[... implement size, getindex, setindex! ... all working perfectly]

"""
    issymmetric(A::LocalMatrix)
Tests whether a LocalMatrix is symmetric
"""
function issymmetric(A::LocalMatrix)
    println("my issymmetric")
    all(LinearAlgebra.issymmetric, [@view A.data[:,:,i,j] for i=1:size(A.data,3), j=1:size(A.data,4)])
end

"""
    isdiag(A::LocalMatrix)
Tests whether a LocalMatrix is diagonal
"""
function isdiag(A::LocalMatrix)
    println("my isdiag")
    all(LinearAlgebra.isdiag, [@view A.data[:,:,i,j] for i=1:size(A.data,3), j=1:size(A.data,4)])
end
```

When I try and run this however, I get

> error in method definition: function LinearAlgebra.isdiag must be explicitly imported to be extended

OK not a problem, I can change the definition to `function LinearAlgebra.isdiag()` instead and it works. But if I also change the definition of the other function to `function LinearAlgebra.issymmetric()` and run a simple test I now get the error

> ERROR: MethodError: no method matching issymmetric(::MyLinearAlgebra.LocalMatrix{Float64})

So I'm stumped. Obviously I have a workaround that lets me continue working for now, but I must be simply misunderstanding how Julia modules work because I can't seem to distinguish between the two functions. Why does one needs to be explicitly extended? Why can the other not? What even is the difference between them in this situation? What is the correct way here to extend a package's module? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly state that you are adding new methods to existing functions so it should be:

```
function LinearAlgebra.issymmetric(A::LocalMatrix)
...
end

function LinearAlgebra.isdiag(A::LocalMatrix)
...
end
```

The reason that you are getting the error most likely is because you forgot to import `LinearAlgebra` in the code that is testing your package.

Note that your constructor also should be corrected:

```
struct LocalMatrix{T} <: AbstractMatrix{T}
    data::Array{T,4}
    function LocalMatrix(data::Array{T,4}) where {T}
        new{T}(data)
    end
end
```

With the current constructor you need to write `LocalMatrix{Float64}(some_arr)` instead of simply `LocalMatrix(some_arr)`. Even worse, if you provide your constructor with a 3-d array you will get a type conversion error, while when you used the syntax that I am proposing one gets `no method matching LocalMatrix(::Array{Int64,3})` which is much more readable for users of your library.

Comment: So in any code testing this library, I will have to explicitly import both `LinearAlgebra` and `MyLinearAlgebra` just to use one of the functions I've written? The imports aren't "carried over" from just importing mine?

Comment: And to be clear your suggestion is also exactly equivalent to writing `import LinearAlgebra: isdiag` in my module definition, while keeping the function definitions the same?

Comment: What you need to import in the testing code depends on what you test. However, a good quality package should contain tests for all its methods and hence I expect your test file to contain the `using LinearAlgrbra` line. Regarding `import` - the standard in Julia is normally to use `using` rather imports (importing single functions from a package is a Pytonish way of writing the code not Julian). Importing a single method to overload will work but is not Julian style.